# With CLion, how to install an executable into a directory only writable by root?

Tags: bash, unix, cmake, permissions, clion

I'm building a C Project with CLion on macOS High Sierra. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(toy C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(toy main.c)
target_compile_options(toy PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c)
target_link_libraries(toy kcgi z)

install(TARGETS toy
        DESTINATION /var/www/fcgi-bin
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_READ
                    GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ
                    WORLD_EXECUTE WORLD_READ)
```

However, on my system, `/var/www/fcgi-bin` is only writable by root:

```
~|⇒ ls -la /var/www/fcgi-bin
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   64 Jun 21 21:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Jun 15 22:45 ..
```

When I try to install the target, I got an error, presumably results from the permission issue:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/sunqingyao/CLionProjects/toy/cmake-build-debug --target install -- -j 2
[100%] Built target toy
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: /var/www/fcgi-bin/toy
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/Users/sunqingyao/CLionProjects/toy/cmake-build-debug/toy" to
  "/var/www/fcgi-bin/toy".


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Using `chmod(1)` on `/var/www/fcgi-bin` is the most obvious solution, but I don't want to modify the permission of a destination directory. What I want is a CMake equivalent of

```
install: kcgi-app
        sudo mkdir -p /var/www/fcgi-bin
        sudo install -m 0555 kcgi-app /var/www/fcgi-bin
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't a programming question - it's a question on how to use macOS

Comment: Run installation with `sudo`.

Comment: Or change the install directory. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html?highlight=cmake_install_prefix

Comment: @ChrisTurner I'm trying to build a project with CMake with CLion on macOS. Do you think all questions about developing on macOS should go to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)? Also, I believe this question applies to all Unix (maybe even Linux) systems, hence the [unix] tag.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I really hope it's so easy, but I'm working with CLion. Do you know how can I run installation with `sudo` with its GUI?

Comment: @kuga That isn't a viable approach to me. If I change the install directory to another, I still have to make it unwritable to other users for security reasons.

Comment: Install it to a diffenent folder (see above) then `sudo cp otherfolder /` in the terminal. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Is there any relation to C language? Seems to be related to CMake and bash only.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm building a C project, so I think it's remotely related? You're right about it's closer relation to bash, though, so I'm editing the tag.

Comment: @nalzok if this were a question about how to develop on macOS, it'd be fine on here - but it's a question about dealing with file permissions and user access

Comment: The problem and the answers would be the same if it was a BASIC, Pascal or FORTRAN project. While C is used, it simply does not matter. Thanks for removing the tag.

Comment: Hm, CLion uses command line with `cmake` for build and install a project. You may try to use the same command line **outside of CLion**. If this works, you may run this command line in bash and prepend it with `sudo` (or GUI analogue supported on Mac). I know this is not a perfect solution. May be someone knows a way for do that inside CLion. BTW, I think notion about CLion should be at the beginning of the question post and in the title - this is the main aspect why common `sudo`-approach don't work directly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I guess that would work, will try out. Personally I prefer Makefile over CMake, and I'm only *forced* to use the latter when working with CLion, so I (incorrecly) thought mentioning CMake implies the use of CLion. Anyway, I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: 1. Make only that file belong to your user and writeable, like `sudo touch /var/www/fcgi-bin/toy; sudo chown sunqingyao /var/www/fcgi-bin/toy`.

Comment: 2. It's not generally accepted practice to compile immediately into production environment, like your `"have to make it unwritable to other users for security reasons"` comment implies. The decision is yours though, as the project might have a special circumstances.